# Difference between fetch and latency in the metrics view

Tags: apiconnect-test-monitor

I've been using IBM's API Connect Test and Monitor and it has been really amazing. I just needed to know what is really meant by fetch vs latency in the metrics view under the dashboard tab as seen in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Good question.  I was *not* able to find a definitive statement in any of the IBM docs (said docs saying "refer to StackOverflow if you have questions").  I suspect 1) "latency": overall time to service your request (i.e. "response time"), and 2) "fetch": the time it takes the back-end to return a response, once it's received and started processing the request.

Comment: @paulsm4 I thought so too as this was the only thing that made sense until I found that occasionally, the fetch time would come larger than the latency. So this cancels our assumption and confirms that both variables are independent of each other. Also I've noticed something interesting. In the performance view under the API Quality tab, you can see a parameter called 'Response Time' in which the tool defines as Latency + Fetch. So if I have to make a guess, I'd say fetch is the time taken to receive the response from the endpoint and maybe latency is the time taken for the test case to run.

Comment: Don't "guess".  Continue researching, find out for sure, and post back what you find.  SUGGESTION: post on an IBM forum (like Developerworks).  Or open a ticket (if your organization has an IBM support agreement).